# How to change "Return to sellers.email@somemail.com" to "Return to Seller's Business Name" in Woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, paypal, woocommerce

I'm using Woocommerce for my current project. Everything is okay. But, when a customer purchases and makes payment through PayPal, PayPal shows messages with Seller's email address. Example:
Before payment:https://i.stack.imgur.com/fk78l.png
After payment https://i.stack.imgur.com/h252d.png

Is there anybody to help?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to update your business name inside your paypal account.

**Note** : Your personal account cannot have a business name. Need to have a **Business account**.

- login to your business account at www.paypal.com
- My Account->My selling tools->My business information.
- Update your business name.

Comment: it should work, i see from your image (transaction id), you are using personal paypal email address, business name is not applicable for personal accounts, if you are using a business account and still dint help, then provide me your button code so that I can see, else you don't know what you really want to do.

Comment: Hey Vimal, maybe you are right. But, how did I solve is just change the sandbox status from admin page. If you enable sandbox, it shows email id and if you disable it, it shows account/business name! Anyway, thanks.